# Modified double slit experiment - what will happen?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

[image]

The attached illustration is a schematic of a slightly modified double slit experiment. Detector D1 detects photons arriving from the upper path, D2 does the same for photons arriving from the lower path.

Assume this experiment takes place in a closed room with no people. A person outside the room has access only to the data taken from each of the detectors.

From what I understand - in the standard setup, if the person looks at the results from all detectors - they see a uniform scatter pattern at D0. If the person disables or removes D1/D2 and then performs the test – they will see an interference pattern.

I am by no means an expert in the field of quantum mechanics, so if there are any errors with the setup above - just let me know. Regardless, even if the setup needs to be changed for some reason, the questions in principle remain the same.

In the scenarios below, all 3 detectors are active. **Which pattern will the person detect at D0 in each scenario?**

1. The person deletes the data captured from D1/D2 without reading it. After that they read the data from D0. Assume the data cannot be recovered after deletion.
2. The person first reads the data from D0. Then they delete the data captured from D1/D2 without reading it. Assume the data cannot be recovered after deletion.
3. The person encrypts the data captured from D1/D2 with a very strong encryption standard. After that they read the data from D0. Assume the encryption key is not known and can only ever be recovered by brute force. Assume that the probability of recovering the encryption key during the lifetime of the universe is very close to 0.
4. Same as scenario (3), but the encryption standard is moderately strong and we can assume the probability of recovering the key is 10%.
5. Same as scenario (3), but the encryption standard is weak and we can assume the probability of recovering the key is 50%.

Comment: In none of the scenarios there will be an interference pattern at D0. In fact even without the detectors D1 and D2 the quantum states are orthogonal and therefore don't interfere. Tomorrow I have time to write a proper answer (if there isn't one by then).

Comment: A person? Not a cat or a bat? What does a person have to do with anything? A baby? A drunk?

Comment: If you know which path photons took, you will get a particle result.  If you don't know which path photons took, you will get an interference pattern.  That result holds true for ALL conceivable double slit experiments that have ever been performed.

Comment: As far as I can tell, whether or not D1 and/or D2 are there will make no difference to any interference pattern observed at D0, as they are outside the path. I suspect that it will not be possible to observe an interference pattern while the Prism is there as it offers the potential to detect which way information. at D0. Normally in this sort of experiment D0 is a photon multiplier that detects the arrival of a photon rather than a screen and the interference pattern is determined by the correlations between the photons and arriving at D0 and D1/D2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual question is whether it's necessary for the experimentalist to know the result of a measurement to make it part of physical reality. The simple answer is no – it's enough to let the observed system interact with any macroscopic device in an irreversible way. Irreversible means that there is no practical way of undoing all the interaction *on the quantum level*. Erasing a hard disk would not bring the system back into the state before the measurement was done, because both the write and erase operations would involve incredibly many quantum degrees of freedom that we can't assume they all end up in the same state independent of what was the measurement outcome.

A more in-depth answer is that you won't see interference here because the quantum states are orthogonal. Let's go through the setup and write down the quantum state created by an incoming photon $|1\rangle_{in}$. Right after the double slit the photon is in a superposition of going through the upper or lower slit
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( |1\rangle_{\color{red}{upper}} + |1\rangle_{\color{cyan}{lower}} \right) \text{.}
$$
Right after the BBO crystal each branch of the photon creates a horizontally and a vertically polarized photon
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( |H\rangle_{\color{red}{upper}} |V\rangle_{\color{red}{upper}} + |H\rangle_{\color{cyan}{lower}} |V\rangle_{\color{cyan}{lower}} \right) \text{.}
$$
They are split depending on their polarization. In the scheme you posted this isn't defined, so let's decide for the case that vertically polarized light is deflected upwards and horizontally polarized light downwards. The quantum state after the Glan-Thompson prism is
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( |H\rangle_{\color{red}{upper}, downwards} |V\rangle_{\color{red}{upper}, upwards} + |H\rangle_{\color{cyan}{lower}, downwards} |V\rangle_{\color{cyan}{lower}, upwards} \right) \text{.}
$$
As you can see, even if you focus the two upwards beams $|V\rangle_{\color{red}{upper}, upwards}$, $|V\rangle_{\color{cyan}{lower}, upwards}$ to the same spot they can't interfere, because they are part of a bigger Hilbert space in which they are *orthogonal* because of $|H\rangle_{\color{red}{upper}, downwards}$ vs. $|H\rangle_{\color{cyan}{lower}, downwards}$. It is like in linear algebra the vectors $\vec{v}_1 = (0, 0, ... , 0, \color{cyan}{0, 1}, 0, ..., 0, 0)$ and $\vec{v}_2 = (0, 0, ... , 0, \color{red}{1, 0}, 0, ..., 0, 0)$ are orthogonal.

Involving the detectors D1/D2 does not change the orthogonality. After the detection the state is
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \color{red}{|D1\rangle} |V\rangle_{\color{red}{upper}, upwards} + \color{cyan}{|D2\rangle} |V\rangle_{\color{cyan}{lower}, upwards} \right) \text{.}
$$
As described above, there is no practical way of undoing the measurement (= entanglement with the macroscopic detection device), so one typically performs a [partial trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_trace)  over the dimension of the Hilbert space describing the detectors. The state, which is now described by a density matrix, is now
$$
\frac{1}{2} \left( |V\rangle_{\color{red}{upper}, upwards} \langle V |_{\color{red}{upper}, upwards} + |V\rangle_{\color{cyan}{lower}, upwards} \langle V |_{\color{cyan}{lower}, upwards} \right) \text{.}
$$
This is just a rigorous way of describing the collapse of the wavefunction. 
Another way of seeing the result after the partial trace is that the detection of a photon at either D1 or D2 has revealed which path the photon actually took. This is dangerous for two reasons.

1. Because it implies that the photon does indeed go through only one slit. So the whole description of the wavefunction would just be a complicated way of describing probabilities.
2. Because if suggests that the collapse of the wavefunction is due to knowledge, while it is actually about orthogonality. The reason for this misconception is that most textbook examples work with idealized detectors where none of the potentially available information is lost.